# Extracting particular column from row and merging columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda series of time difference stored in a variable called min_time_diff.
Now I want to return the row with the minimum time difference which I could do with

```
out = df3.loc[min_time_diff.idxmin()]
```

but the I just want it to return a particular column value in it called `'Date'` and create a new pandas dataframe with a few column values.
I have stored them in separate variables like a,b,c...etc
Do I have to do each time with `df['col1']=a` `df['col2']=b` or is there a easier shorter way?

edit-
when I do this-
out = df3.loc[min_time_diff.idxmin()]
it returns a row which has a lot of columns in it.I want the idxmin to just return the column named 'Date' from it.

and then I have a variables like id-'197_%' code=487...I want to merge all these variables and the result obtained from out into a new dataframe.

Comment: How about: `out = df3.loc[min_time_diff.idxmin(), ['col1', 'col2']]` ? The second parameter can be a list of columns.

Comment: @jpp but how to store values in those columns which are stored in variables like a b etc

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by a b etc. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @jpp sorry for the confusion...see the edits

Comment: Sorry, I'm now more confused. Got lost at `variables like id-'197_%' code=487`. Think we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.assign()` method, see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 11), 'B': np.random.randn(10)})
```

> Where the value is a callable, evaluated on df:

```
>>> df.assign(ln_A = lambda x: np.log(x.A))
    A         B      ln_A
0   1  0.426905  0.000000
1   2 -0.780949  0.693147
2   3 -0.418711  1.098612
3   4 -0.269708  1.386294
4   5 -0.274002  1.609438
5   6 -0.500792  1.791759
6   7  1.649697  1.945910
7   8 -1.495604  2.079442
8   9  0.549296  2.197225
9  10 -0.758542  2.302585
```

You can also assign multiple columns at once this way, even if their values depend on each other:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> df.assign(B=df.A, C=lambda x:x['A']+ x['B'])
    A  B  C
 0  1  1  2
 1  2  2  4
 2  3  3  6
```

**Edit - great catch by Jon Clements:**

Assigning multiple columns within the same assign is possible. For Python 3.6 and above, later items in ‘**kwargs’ may refer to newly created or modified columns in ‘df’; items are computed and assigned into ‘df’ in order. For Python 3.5 and below, the order of keyword arguments is not specified, you cannot refer to newly created or modified columns. All items are computed first, and then assigned in alphabetical order.